# Caldav Radicale sever not responding properly to event put request

Tags: caldav, radicale

I am trying to add the event to the radicale server, but its responding with "Precondition Failed" message. There might be something wrong in my request but I am not able to get it. 
Below is my request :

```
PUT /user/user1.ics/20130810T095754Z-1926-1000-1-3_media80-20130810T095803Z.ics HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5232
User-Agent: Evolution/2.28.3.1
If-None-Match: *
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 720

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:-//Ximian//NONSGML Evolution Calendar//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:/freeassociation.sourceforge.net/Tzfile/Asia/Kolkata
X-LIC-LOCATION:Asia/Kolkata
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:IST
DTSTART:19701014T230000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20130810T095754Z-1926-1000-1-3@media
DTSTAMP:20130810T095754Z
DTSTART;TZID=/freeassociation.sourceforge.net/Tzfile/Asia/Kolkata:
 20130810T200000
DTEND;TZID=/freeassociation.sourceforge.net/Tzfile/Asia/Kolkata:
 20130810T203000
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:2
SUMMARY:Test4
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20130810T095803Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20130810T095803Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the resource at

/user/user1.ics/20130810T095754Z-1926-1000-1-3_media80-20130810T095803Z.ics

does not already exist ?

The

```
If-None-Match: *
```

header indicates that the PUT should fail with "412 Precondition Failed" if there is already a resource at that URI.

Comment: I think that worked, the resource already existed..... I will check more...... till then thanks :)